# Finding the process launching keyring prompt

Tags: kde, gnome-keyring

Couple of days ago my machine (Manjaro, KDE) started launching keyring prompts. I'm obviously worried and want to find a culprit, but not sure how can I do that. In addition to lacking knowledge of how to tie window to a particular process, the prompt captures focus and prevents me from doing anything except for:

- Filling in the password and confirming (ha-ha, fat chance)
- Cancelling (leading to window disappearance and by thus losing any possible trace of problem)
- Ctrl + Alt + F2 to switch to another tty, but obviously then I can't communicate well with X on different tty.

I couldn't find any logs for gcr-prompter in `journalctl -u gcr-prompter` (not sure if it has any relation to problem, but this is as far as my google ressearch goes). The focus capture issue prevents me even from taking screenshot, so i have to resort to infamous phone camera technique to visualize the problem:

[image]

How to trace back such an issue and find the rogue process?

Comment: _looks like_ it was jetbrains toolbox. not 100% sure though.